# Display Boolean value in radio button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have the following loop to display data in a view, I need help displaying radio button. I have `flag` field in my database it has value either 0 or 1. I want to display that in radio button.

```
@foreach (var item in prodInfo)
{
    @item.flag
}
```

[image]

Comment: You mean you have to hide and show the radio button based on boolean value?

Comment: Thanks! no set the value, if value is true or 1  then "On" is selected otherwise "off"radio button selected

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var n = 0; // set your bool value here 0/1
if(n===1)
{
 document.getElementById("yourRadiobtn").checked = true;
}
else
{
 document.getElementById("yourRadiobtn").checked = false;
}
```

```html
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="yourRadiobtn">Item
```

If you're using a bool type then

```js
var  n = false ; // set your bool value here (true/false)
if(n === true)
{
 document.getElementById("yourRadiobtn").checked = true;
}
else
{
 document.getElementById("yourRadiobtn").checked = false;
}
```

```html
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="yourRadiobtn">Item
```

Comment: Thank you! added image as an example, also can you add your code in for each as listed in my question?

Comment: I did MVC very long time ago! need to spend more time to get it adjusted. this may help ?https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/radios